# Backgroundworker progresschanged event c#

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am using background worker in winforms.
In `backgroundworker_progresschanged` event `e.userstate` is a item which is to be added in the `listbox`.
At the same time I want to show the `e.userstate` on the popup window.

Here is my code:

In `backgroundworker_progresschanged` event `setlable()` is a method which is from the another class.

```
 public void SetLable(string pbValue)
    {
        try
        {
            label1.Text = pbValue;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

I want to add `userstate` in `listbox2` and at the same time want to show that on popup window which i have created in another form.
I have comment out the `listbox.items.add` because both are not working at the same time.

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> result1 = new List<string>();

        var found = obj.getFiles();

        foreach (var item in found)
        {
            if (item.Contains("ERROR"))
            {
                result1.Add(item);

                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(0, item);

            }
            else
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        }
        e.Result = result1;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.UserState != null)
            pop.SetLable(e.UserState.ToString());
       // listBox2.Items.Add(e.UserState);

    }
```

I want both to be work at same time.

```
   pop.SetLable(e.UserState.ToString());
// listBox2.Items.Add(e.UserState);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you intending to add UserState to the listbox even if it's null?

Comment: Why there is `try/catch` around setting text of label? What exceptions do you catch?

Comment: _"both are not working at the same time"_ - not working how? One gets set but not the other? You get an error (and if so, what error?)? Something else?

Comment: Create a class with all object you want to report (state object).  Then pass an instance  the class as the reporting object.

Comment: Also, consider converting `item` to all uppercase before checking for "ERROR": `if (item.ToUpper().Contains("ERROR"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An if statement only executes the statement immediately following it.  If you intend for more than one thing to occur, use a block:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.UserState != null)
    {
        pop.SetLable(e.UserState.ToString());
        listBox2.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
    }
}
```

Get into the habit of immediately typing both brackets in when you create every single if statement (same goes for any else portions!).  Even single statements should be enclosed in a block for if/else statements...that way you can add things to your logic later and not fall into this type of subtle bug.

Comment: Even if this isn't the 'answer' (and I suspect it is), still worth an upvote

Comment: This Works! Thank you so much!